# WakefulBroadcastReceiver did not wake up the screen

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, wakelock

I'm working on GCM to get the notification.
I supposed to wakeup screen device when notification receives.

How can I do that?

When testing the apps, the device only play notification sound and vibrating, but no wakeup screen.

here is the snippet of WakefullBroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

and IntentService:

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
//NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String LOG_TAG = GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                        "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            sendNotification("Notification: "
                    + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("TITLE")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker("New Message");


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside on GCMNotificationIntentService onHandleIntent you must run:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "wakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

and after a few seconds to turn off the screen should run

```
wakeLock.release();
```